# Python + Selenium: webdriver find XPath

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, find, element

I want to click the link /any/path (on both the same) by using:

```
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath()
```

First I want to find "Firstname". From "Firstname" I want to find "Lastname".
I don't want to find "Firstname" and "Lastname" separately.

I need an XPath which includes "Firstname" and from there to "Lastname".
I know that i can find it seperately with `"//*[contains(text(),'Firstname')]"`.

I want to click /any/path.

Note: The path changes, so I can't search for just the path:

[image]

Is there any other possibility to find "Lastname" via "Firstname"?

Comment: Please post code as code not as images, thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking... you want to find both or ???

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to python etc. and I'm not that well in speaking english ^^

Comment: How is going? Did you try my answer?

Comment: @RatmirAsanov yes but it would not work because the path changes.. nevertheless thanks for your help!

Comment: @Julian, I have updated my answer. Check it, please.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to find the node with some text e.g. **Firstname** and with reference to that trying to find another node with some other text e.g. **Lastname** you can write a function to call with these two parameters (*Firstname* and *Lastname*) as follows :

```
def test_me(firstName, lastName):
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h1/a[@class='name-link' and contains(.='" + firstName + "')]//following::a[@class='name-link' and contains(.='" + lastName + "')]")
```

Now you can call the function when ever you need with the two arguments as follows :

```
test_me("Firstname", "Lastname")
```